# Compare last digit

Tags: pandas, logical-operators

A have a csv file with columns as below:

```
Last_Price, Price, Marked
3,2.89,
1.99,2.09,
3.9,3.79,
```

I created a pandas dataframe named subdf.
I want to compare last digit of Last_Price and Price columns, If they are not equal I assign 'X' to the column 'Marked' otherwise leave it as blank or NaN.

I have tried:

```
subdf['Marked'] = np.where([x.strip()[-1] for x in subdf['Last_Price']] == [x.strip()[-1] for x in subdf['Price']],
'X',
np.nan)
```

It says: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'

I tried the below as well but it didn't work. It doesn't capture last digit.
I guess I need a for loop as well.

```
str(subdf['Price']).strip()[-1]
```

Comment: `df[colname].astype('str').str[-1]`

Comment: Problem with this is 3.90 will return 9 because astype converts 3.90 (float) to 3.9 (string).

Comment: @ScottBoston If a particular format is needed `df[colname].apply('{:.2f}'.format).str[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.

It assumes that all prices have 2 digits or less after the decimal point. And that for "3" you want to compare for the "0" in "3.00" and
not the last digit "3".

Multiplying by 10 moves only the last digit to the end

Then doing a MOD (%) division by 1 removes the front.

Please note: I removed the spaces from the csv captions to allow proper importing of the names

```
import pandas as pd
import io   

TESTDATA = """Last_Price,Price,Marked
3,2.89,
1.99,2.09,
3.9,3.79,"""

subdf = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(TESTDATA), sep=",")

subdf.loc[((subdf['Last_Price'] * 10) % 1) != 
          ((subdf['Price'] * 10) % 1), 'Marked'] = 'X'

print(subdf)
```

The result

```
   Last_Price  Price Marked  
0        3.00   2.89      X         
1        1.99   2.09    NaN         
2        3.90   3.79      X
```

If you really want to **compare** against the **string output**,
so the "**9**" from "3.**9**" vs "3.7**9**" match, then import the dataframe as a str

```
import pandas as pd
import io   

TESTDATA = """Last_Price,Price,Marked
3,2.89,
1.99,2.09,
3.9,3.79,"""

subdf = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(TESTDATA), sep=",", dtype='str')
subdf.loc[(subdf['Last_Price'].str.slice(-1)) != 
           (subdf['Price'].str.slice(-1)), 'Marked'] = 'X'
print(subdf)
```

New result

```
  Last_Price Price Marked 
0          3  2.89      X        
1       1.99  2.09    NaN        
2        3.9  3.79    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you.
Using this module approach worked as expected.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, since you are new here: If you post a question, try to post a full code example as well as the expected output. Your test data was very good, with a result example it would have been easier to answer the question...